# How to use bootstrap alert event close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#alerts

We are able to see code like:

```js
$('#my-alert').bind('closed', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

But what is  `#my-alert`?

Answer (score 0):

`#my-alert` is a CSS ID selector which identifies the element to which you are binding a function (`my-alert` is just an example, insert your element's ID).

Here's an example alert DIV with the ID `alert1`:

```html
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in" id="alert1">
    <p>Alert!</p>
</div>
```

There are many other ways to select an element. I would read up on [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 3.0 you could use:

```js
$('#my-alert').bind('closed.bs.alert', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

`#my-alert` is the CSS ID for your alert div